# Oracle - explanation of hierarchical query

Tags: sql, oracle, combinations, hierarchical

I have a question about hierarchical SQL.

sample data:

```
create table group_ (
group_id number);

create table set_(
set_id number);

insert into group_ values(1);
insert into group_ values(2);
insert into group_ values(3);
insert into set_ values(1);
insert into set_ values(2);
```

SQL:

```
SELECT  group_id,
        sys_connect_by_path(set_id, ', '), LEVEL
FROM    set_
CROSS   JOIN group_
CONNECT BY prior set_id < set_id
ORDER   BY group_id, combo nulls first,lvl;
```

My goal is to get all possible combinations of 2 tables, and it's working, but I've got repeated values so i have to use distinct/unique caluse.
The question is - why they are appearing?

Comment: "And it's working"? That's not true (not for the query you **posted**, anyway; perhaps you ran something else). For example, you have `combo` and `lvl` in `order by`, but they are not defined anywhere else in the query. So, let's start with that. Then: What do you mean by "al possible combinations of 2 tables"? I have no idea what that means. In your query you cross-join to `group` but then you don't use it anywhere else. Perhaps you meant to do the hierarchical step on `set_` first, and only then cross join the result to `group`? Hard to know.

Comment: Why not simply `SELECT * FROM set_ CROSS JOIN group_`? Not clear what you like to get by "all possible combinations"

Comment: Be aware of function [GROUP_ID](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions079.htm#SQLRF00646). Do you like to get the `GROUP_ID` **function** or **column** of table `group_`? Also CONNECT BY `PRIOR set_id < set_id` looks at least "very uncommon".

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a `UNION ALL`. Effectively you're selecting everything from `group_` and then selecting it again after joining with the `set_` table.

Change to `UNION` and the duplicates will be removed.

See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7d079/3

Comment: I know how to cut them. I Want to know why they appearing in select

Comment: Because you were (before you edited your question) doing a `UNION ALL` which meant you were selecting the whole `group_` table and then also selecting, as part of the same result, the results of your second query so you got everything from `group_` twice.